# Assign expression to a variable and use it in another function

Tags: python

I got the following code, that should be used in another function, so I want to pass it using a variable

```
soup.find("div", {"class" : "article-entry text"}).text.replace('\n', "")
```

Using

```
textFormat = "soup.find("div", {"class" : "article-entry text"}).text.replace('\n', "")"
```

doesn't work obviously. Do I have to escape characters? How?

What would be the best way to execute the content of textFormat. Like so?

```
text = exec(textFormat)
```

Thanks!

Comment: It might be a good idea to explain in details what you are trying to archive with that.

Comment: I got a big function, that can be applied to different websites for scraping except for this expression. This is why I want to put everything in one function and only pass the scraping statement, which is different for every website

Comment: Then you should have one base class where the subclasses overwrite one function.

Comment: But the function I am talking about is around 60 lines of code. I got only two minor changes, so overwriting the whole function seems like not the best idea, right?

Comment: You don't overwrite the whole function. Just a class method that runs the code that changes.

Comment: Do you have a good example for that? I am a self-taught beginner ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use lambda:

```
soup_find = lambda x,y: soup.find(x,y).text.replace('\n', '')
soup_find("div", {"class" : "article-entry text"})
```

Comment: Thank you. Lamdba seems to be coming up on my journey to learn python pretty often. Any good resource to learn it for a beginner? Have a hard time understanding what this is doing..

Comment: @user2252633 lambda is one of the useful things, if u sure know how to use that) https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape quotes that your string is surrounded by. Moreover you need to use raw string, to escape other chars. So ...:

```
textFormat = r'soup.find("div", {"class" : "article-entry text"}).text.replace(\'\n\', "")'
```

But if you need to apply function that is have partially  fixed elements you should just use `partial` from *functools*, not this ad hoc with `eval`.
Using partial you can fix common arguments and pass others that are not common on every call.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in another function like this:

```
def textFormat():
    return soup.find("div", {"class" : "article-entry text"}).text.replace('\n', "")
```

Then use it like this:

```
text = textFormat()
```

If you want to pass it to another function:

```
def func(another_func):
    return another_func()

func(textFormat)
```

Comment: Question was about variable :) But this variant too usable for sure

Comment: @JeffersonHoup `textFormat` IS a variable and you can pass it to another function like this `func(textFormat)`

Comment: Yeah, all right. In my first post I mean: "U're just create a function", because that expression: text = textFormat()
will return value of func, because of "()". After update all right ) nvm so